# Spark Cluster incomprehensible output

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

I am executing a [third-part tool](https://github.com/broadinstitute/gatk/blob/9e4e41cbf2740ec3e5d41a5d3bbf9365bb2b51dd/src/main/java/org/broadinstitute/hellbender/tools/spark/pipelines/BwaAndMarkDuplicatesPipelineSpark.java), implemented in Spark, in cluster mode.

When executed on a single machine, during the execution was produced comprehensible output, but when executed in cluster mode, after some minutes I can observe this kind of output:

```
...
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 95.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 199, 10.0.0.13, executor 5, partition 95, ANY, 5585 bytes)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 87.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 191) in 442674 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 5) (80/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 96.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 200, 10.0.0.13, executor 4, partition 96, ANY, 5585 bytes)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 88.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 192) in 427022 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 4) (81/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 97.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 201, 10.0.0.13, executor 6, partition 97, ANY, 5586 bytes)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 89.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 193) in 434826 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 6) (82/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 98.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 202, 10.0.0.13, executor 5, partition 98, ANY, 5586 bytes)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 90.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 194) in 428479 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 5) (83/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 99.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 203, 10.0.0.13, executor 4, partition 99, ANY, 5586 bytes)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 92.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 196) in 421363 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 4) (84/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 100.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 204, 10.0.0.13, executor 6, partition 100, ANY, 5585 bytes)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 91.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 195) in 436868 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 6) (85/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 101.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 205, 10.0.0.13, executor 7, partition 101, ANY, 5585 bytes)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 93.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 197) in 423796 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 7) (86/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 102.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 206, 10.0.0.13, executor 5, partition 102, ANY, 5585 bytes)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 95.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 199) in 431473 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 5) (87/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 103.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 207, 10.0.0.13, executor 7, partition 103, ANY, 5335 bytes)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 94.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 198) in 448226 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 7) (88/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 96.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 200) in 435101 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 4) (89/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 97.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 201) in 423836 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 6) (90/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 98.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 202) in 415700 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 5) (91/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 99.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 203) in 410550 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 4) (92/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 100.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 204) in 420337 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 6) (93/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 103.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 207) in 318385 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 7) (94/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 101.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 205) in 421965 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 7) (95/104)
INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 102.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 206) in 425816 ms on 10.0.0.13 (executor 5) (96/104)
...
```

which does not give much information. Is there a way to see the output which was possible to observe in local execution?

Furthermore after tens minutes I can observe that CPU workloads decreases almost to 0% in both machines, while just few minutes earlier they were almost 100% busy. It may be due to few resources allocated during the `spark-submit`? I don't know it, since this output doesn't give any clue, what could I do to investigate or obtain some more valuable info?

I tried for example to connect to http://localhost:4040 as suggested [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html), but I don't receive any response

Comment: What's your question then?

Comment: thanks for your reply; I'd like to access to the usual stack trace that I could access when the tool was executed in local mode if possible (here I receive only the reported stack trace which doesn't give me any info about the proceeding of the task). Or, do you know any other solution to inspect the job progress?

Comment: Are you experiencing any issue? I can't see it in the question. What are you looking for?

Comment: Well yes, the issue is that the tool get stuck at a certain point, neither the stack trace shows any progress. I would liked something to "debug" it, but if you can help me with the issue even better. For any other details, feel free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the normal stack-trace that I was usual to observe in local mode, for how is designed Spark, it is indeed natural to find it in **Spark Worker's** stack-trace.

To access it, I connected with a browser (since I am connected in SSH with a VM I use [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/)) to http://localhost:8081 of the node containing the Spark Worker during the job execution: clicking on "stderr" the required stack-trace is shown. Or, in Worker node file system, in something similar to /spark/work/app-20180216182621-0001/2/stderr is saved the stack-trace output.

I wasn't able to access to http://localhost:8081 and http://localhost:4040 earlier because I'm provisioning Spark with Docker and I didn't specified these ports in docker-compose file. But this isn't relevant in this question.